# Android login system

Tags: java, android, authentication

I am completely unaware of all the Android features and available libraries.

I just designed a login system to practice it. I have referred to a few books and tutorials.

**Layout**

I am using relative layout. And have two `EditText` and one button for login and one button to start register activity.

**Activity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email, password;
    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    }

    public void checkLogin(View view){
        final String emailText = email.getText().toString().trim();
        final String passwordTex = password.getText().toString().trim();

        Response.Listener<String> successListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    if(jsonResponse.getInt("status") == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonResponse.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SubjectActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else if(jsonResponse.getInt("status") == 1 || jsonResponse.getInt("status") == -2){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonResponse.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Serious error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }catch(JSONException e){

                }
                progress.hide();
            }
        };

        Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progress.hide();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

        if(emailText.isEmpty() || passwordTex.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter all the details",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            progress.setMessage("Logging in");
            progress.show();
            StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.LOGIN_URL, successListener, errorListener) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("email", emailText);
                    params.put("password", passwordTex);
                    return params;
                }
            };

            ReqQueue.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(req);
        }
    }

    public void goToRegisterLayout(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } //It will start register activity if register button is clicked
}
```

I am using `Volley` to read from PHP.

**My Queue class as follows**

```
public class ReqQueue extends Application{
    private static ReqQueue instance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized ReqQueue getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
        if(requestQueue == null){
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        }
        return  requestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req){
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
}
```

If you legends suggest me some other way, I am open to accept it. Every single point from you will really help me. You can suggest new best way of doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

1. Variables names are a little misleading - I'd expect `email` to be a `String`, not a `View`.  Try `emailView` or `emailTextView`, or even better, since they're private `mEmailTextView`.
2. All the methods in `LoginActivity` are `public`.  There's very little chance that any of those methods are going to be accessed outside of the instance itself, they can probably be private.
3. Your `ProgressDialog` is package-private, just because it's default.  If you want something package-private, that's fine, but you probably don't (and if you do, you probably want to comment it).  Generally, go for as private as possible (private, protected, package-private, public, in that order).
4. You have large blocks of code that aren't super easy to read.  Try breaking your code up into bite-sized methods with descriptive names.  Java can get very verbose, so modularity and organization goes a long way.
5. There is a library called "Gson" which converts JSON to Java objects that's very nice and clean and eliminates tons of boilerplate.
6. Why is `getInstance` synchronized?
7. Is there a reason that `addToReqQueue` is generic?  I can't see that it's doing anything (the generic type is not used in the method body).
8. Convention is that most Strings are stored somewhere (either as constants, or in a file, or something).  This isn't critical, though.